# Rigging with pre-existing Mixamo animation not working

Tags: animation, rigging, mixamo

I had a model that I wanted to use cloth simulation on, I have utilized a custom character with mixamo animation in them, for the jacket that I want the animation on, when I try to parent with automatic weights, it chagnes the location of it, I have tried doing it manually using the vertex groups and I still am having issues with it.
[image]

Original model before automatic weight paint

Post automatic weight paint
[image]

as you can see it messes up the location of the jacket even though automatic weight paint should have done a good job of preserving it, I needed it parented bc I want to apply a cloth simulation on that Jacket. Why is this the case, I never have had this issue when rigging from scratch

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put your armature in *Rest Pose*, apply the *Mirror* modifier of the coat, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to *Unparent and Keep Transformation*, put it at the right position, maybe apply its scale, parent to the armature *With Automatic Weights*, create a vertex group that will be the *Pin Group* of your cloth, also give *Collision* to the body, and it should work.

Comment: Ok will try that

Comment: as soon as I parent with the armature, it moves back in space

Comment: have you first unparent?

Comment: yes I unparented it, and re parented it same issue

Comment: Could you please share your latest version?